# Executing a custom query using the ORMLite query builder

Tags: android, ormlite, query-builder

I read all documentation about orm lite, also looking on net but didn't find right answers. I want to execute this statement:

```
SELECT * from Drive where day_number=150;
```

I have class that represent table:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName="Drive")
public class Drive{

    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int drive_id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String start_time;

    @DatabaseField
    private String end_time;

    @DatabaseField
    private String price;

    @DatabaseField
    private String distance;

    @DatabaseField
    private String day_number;

    @DatabaseField
    private String week_number;

    @DatabaseField
    private String month;

    getters and setters ...
}
```

When i run:

```
List<Drive> today = getHelper().getVoznjaDao().queryBuilder().where().
        eq("day_number","150").query();
```

I get `NullPointerExeption`, and it's not because there is no record for 150 in database.
Please help i am desperate.

Comment: Please edit your post and show the first 5 lines of the exception.

Comment: Ok, i will read that, considering this question, i get NullPointerExeption exactly on this line List<Drive> today = getHelper().getVoznjaDao().queryBuilder().where().
        eq("day_number","150").query(); , what implies that today is null, from what i can conclude that query isn't good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine in terms of the query-builder logic.  I suspect that something to do with your wiring is incorrect however.  In your comments you mention that the NPE happens on the query line.

```
List<Drive> today = getHelper().getVoznjaDao().queryBuilder().where().
    eq("day_number","150").query();
```

Most likely this means that either:

- `getHelper()` is returning a `null` helper instance
- `getVoznjaDao()` is returning a `null` DAO
- or there are bugs in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/)

`today` being `null` would not cause a NPE since it is not dereferenced on the line.  Certainly a bug in ORMLite is not out of the question but I would first check with a debugger to see if the `getHelper()` or `getVoznjaDao()` calls are returning `null`.  I suspect you will find the bug at that point.